# Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

Tags: terraform, private-key

Using terraform I want to copy certain files as soon as the VM is up and running. Trying to do this using File provisioned. But no luck yet. Below is the error I get

Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found

I am using a windows machine and using this host machine to copy files to a certain location in a new VM.

```
resource "null_resource" remoteExecProvisionerWFolder {
depends_on = [
  azurerm_virtual_machine.bastion_vm
]
provisioner "file" {
source      = "test.txt"
destination = "/tmp/test.txt"
}

connection {
host     = data.azurerm_public_ip.test.ip_address
type     = "ssh"
user     = var.usernameprivate_key = file("./id_rsa_xyz.ppk")
timeout = "2m"
agent    = "false"
}
```

Appriciate a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
connection {
host     = data.azurerm_public_ip.test.ip_address
type     = "ssh"
user     = var.username
private_key = file("./id_rsa_xyz")
timeout = "2m"
agent    = "false"
}
```

Otherwise create a private key with openssh
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement#user-key-generation

And then use that pair instead. It usually works with .pem files